# Why using 'They' instead of 'You' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, orthography

I have a question about this sentence I have found during my daily study rutine of English learning:

> Anyone have anything **they**'d like to add to the agenda?

I don't understand why is used **'they'** pronoun instead of **'you'** . I suppose the person is speaking to the audience, for that reason I think **'You'** is the way correct.

> Anyone have anything **you**'d like to add to the agenda?

Can you explain to me?

Comment: See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they

Comment: The sense is  "Does any one (of the people present) have anything they (he or she) would like to add?"

Comment: "Anyone" agrees with a third person singular verb not with the second person/"you" form, which is why you use "does" (or "is") not "do" (or "are") with "anyone". As mentioned, "they" is singular here.

Comment: I didn't have any idea about "Singular they"!. Thank you guys, I will start to read about that.